# PowerShell bulk contact creation from csv

Tags: powershell, active-directory

How can I bulk create AD contacts? I try something like this. I have only First and Last name in my CSV.

```
$CSVPath = "C:\mycontacts.csv"

Import-Csv $CSVPath | foreach{New-ADObject -Type Contact -Name $_.FirstName - OtherAttributes @{'FirstName'=$_.FirstName;'LastName'=$_.LastName} - Path "OU=Contacts,OU=Lab,DC=MYDC,DC=com"}
```

This is my error message:
New-ADObject : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Name'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At line:3 char:64

[image]

This is my CSV

Comment: Show us the first 3 or 4 lines (sanitized) of the CSV. Does it have headers?, What is the delimiter character used (`Import-Csv` defaults to comma), Are there entries where FirstName is left blank?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for showing us the csv file you are working with.

We can now see the delimiter character used is a semi-colon.

Fix the code by letting Import-Csv know that it should not use the default comma by adding the `-Delimiter` parameter:

```
Import-Csv $CSVPath -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object {
    New-ADObject -Type Contact -Name $_.FirstName -DisplayName ('{0} {1}' -f $_.FirstName, $_.LastName) -Path "OU=Contacts,OU=Lab,DC=MYDC,DC=com"
}
```

Also, you have added spaces between the dash and the parameter names here `- OtherAttributes` and here `- Path` that should not be there.

Perhaps also, I could interest you to start using [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) on cmdlets that can take many parameters.
This will help you keep your code readable and maintainable by not having to use long..LONG lines of code.

```
Import-Csv $CSVPath -Delimiter ';' | ForEach-Object {
    $splat = @{
        Type        = 'Contact'
        Name        = $_.FirstName
        Path        = "OU=Contacts,OU=Lab,DC=MYDC,DC=com"
        DisplayName = '{0} {1}' -f $_.FirstName, $_.LastName
        # more parameters can be set here, mostly using 'OtherAttributes'
        # make sure you use the LDAP attribute names with correct casing
        OtherAttributes = @{'givenName'      = $_.FirstName
                            'sn'             = $_.LastName
                            'mail'           = $_.EmailAddress
                            'proxyAddresses' = $_.EmailAddress
                           }        }
    New-ADObject @splat
}
```

---

**Note:** The `OtherAttributes` item lets you set more AD attributes using a Hashtable than the `Get-ADObject cmdlet` offers through its normal parameters.
Take extra care here that you use the **LDAP attribute names** in their correct casing.
LDAP attributenames can be found for instance [here](http://www.phpldaptools.com/reference/Default-Schema-Attributes/#ad-contact-types)

Comment: Many thanks for your help. But I still have issuess. Now I get: " 
New-ADObject : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: FirstName"

I try first and second solution you provided

Comment: @IvanRadunković Ah, didn't check first.. The [New-ADObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/new-adobject) doesn't have parameters `FirstName` or `LastName`. Only `Name` and `DisplayName`. I have updated my answer for this

Comment: Wow. You saved me. Many thanks for your help. Now it's working fine. Thank you again kind Sir

Comment: One more thing, how can I add mail parameter to this? I try with Mail, ExternalEmailAddress, Email, nothing works. I don't want anything special, all users can have same email, string, just want to know how can I add email. So when i open contact I can see E-Mail field filled with email that i provided.

Comment: @IvanRadunković I have edited my answer (only the second part where I used splatting) to show how you can add more attributes like `mail`. Please also see the NOTE at the end. The code of course assumes you have a column in the CSV file for `EmailAddress`..

Comment: Once again many thanks. I have EmailAddress in CSV. It's ok now :)